# How to create a route that will allow me to search keywords and display the results (other than the default)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rspec, routes

As part of a course, I am building an app to search for recipes on http://www.recipepuppy.com/?i=chocolate&q=  using a key word, return an array of hashes with the items I want for each recipe (thumbnail image, name, ingredients) and display all recipes found in a table. I have successfully rendered the table for the default search 'chocolate'. I now need to create a route that will allow me to type a search term (i.e bread) in the url: http://localhost:3000/?search=bread.

I have the following controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = params[:looking_for] || 'chocolate'
    @recipes = Recipe.for(@search)
  end
end
```

I can't figure out how to create a route that will allow me to search other keywords and display the results. I'm not sure if I need to add something to the controller, or just the routes or both?

**EDIT**

This is the rspec test that I can't get to pass:

```
it "displays page for alternate search term (bread)" do
    visit "recipes/index?search=bread"
    expect(page).to have_content 'Our Daily Bread in a Crock - Weekly Make and Bake Rustic Bread'   
  end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's not working with your current code? Have you created a route for this controller action, or tested it by sending the request with a `looking_for` param?

Comment: hi @maxpleaner , the error is coming from the rspec test we were given to test our code.  This is the test that is failing: ```it "displays page for alternate search term (bread)" do
    visit "recipes/index?search=bread"
    expect(page).to have_content 'Our Daily Bread in a Crock - Weekly Make and Bake Rustic Bread'   
  end
```

Comment: you're using the wrong parameter name, In the controller action it's `looking_for` but in the test you're using `search`. Also please show the relevant line in routes.rb.

Answer (score 0):

so if we look at this url we have different parts

```
 http://localhost:3000/search?keyword=bread
```

`http://localhost:3000` is the base url

`/search` is the path and

`?keyword=bread` is what we call the query string (everything after the `?` in a url)

Now, where you display your search form this is what you need to create the route for, so index for recipes).

```
# routes.rb
resources :restaurants, only: :index
```

There you display the form. Now it is important, that

1. it is a form that issues a GET request
2. this get request will go to `recipes#index` too

Once you submit the form, it will attach the query string to the url and you can handle it in the controller.

The form could look something like this (you should use a form helper)

```
# views/recipes/index.html.erb
<form action="/recipes" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then the incoming http request will have the following url

```
GET /recipes?keyword=something_you_typed
```

And in the controller you can handle it like so:

```
# controllers/recipes_controller.rb
  def index
    if params[:keyword]
      @recipes = Recipe.where(name: params[:keyword])
    else
      @recipes = Recipe.all
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hi Clara, thanks for your help. Our instructor just wants us to type the search word into the query string, so we don't need to create a search form. I have edited my initial question to include the rspec that isn't passing.

Comment: Ok, with the code for the controller that I provided - I took a little bit of different variables, but can you make sense of it? It doesn't matter, if the query string comes from a form or is typed manually. :) If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask!